# Правильная реализация метода Dispose

Tags: c#, классы, сборщик-мусора

Есть класс **А**, у него 4 текстовых поля **А1,А2,А3,А4**.
Я хочу реализовать метод  Dispose для класса, т.к. в его полях находится большой текст, а используется он всего 1 раз.

**Скажите, будет ли достаточно в моем случае, если сделаю так?**

```
Dispose()
{
   А1 = null;
   А2 = null;
   А3 = null;
   А4 = null;
}
```

Или может нужно просто сделать А1 = ""?

Comment: Не надо. Dispose предназначен не для помощи сборщику мусора, а для освобождения внешних (unmanaged) ресурсов.

Comment: Т.е. мне вообще никак освобождать ресурсы самостоятельно?

Comment: Какие ресурсы? "Давайте договоримся об определениях и спор разрешится сам собой."

Comment: @LeonardBertone в С# есть сборщик мусора. Он сам все делает. Освобождать руками нужно внешние ресурсы и, например, низкоуровневые соединения с базой данных или файловые дескрипторы

Comment: я ступил, извините.  Я думал, что если  удалю длинные строки, то программа станет меньше памяти занимать. кажется, я ошибся

Comment: _"если удалю длинные строки, то программа станет меньше памяти занимать"_ -- строки в .NET интернированы. почитайте [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479053/#479064)

Comment: @Stack интернированы по умолчанию только строковые литералы. В вашем ответе, кстати, об этом тоже было написано.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34983/discussion-on-question-by-leonard-bertone----dispose).

Comment: @LeonardBertone "если удалю длинные строки, то программа станет меньше памяти занимать" - если эти строки не интернированы (т.е. это не строковые литералы в коде, а просто строки, собранные из других строк, или полученные извне, и для них не был вызван метод `String.Intern` - вами, или кем-то еще в коде используемых вами библиотек) - то такие строки будут собраны сборщиком мусора при отсутствии ссылок на них. Достаточно легко проверить - если вызов `String.IsInterned` в коде вернул false, то код, которым вы эту строку получили, `String.Intern` не вызывал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы не работаете в своем классе с неуправляемыми ресурсами и вы не планируете использовать свой класс вместе с using, то реализовывать IDisposable не нужно. И обнулять ссылки тоже не нужно.

---

Метод Dispose определен в интерфейсе IDisposable, который используется в .NET Framework в разных классах.
На реализацию IDisposable можно **[посмотреть в исходниках](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/idisposable.cs,1f55292c3174123d,references)**. (Надесь никто не будет спорить, что в исходниках .NET правильные реализации этого интерфейса).
Там же можно посмотреть на **комментарии разработчиков .NET**
На скриншоте страницы справа - комментарии разработчиков, а слева - это ссылки на реализацию IDisposable в разных классах.

Один из примеров реализации IDisposable из .NET Framework:

```
class SimpleMonitor : IDisposable {
    public void Enter() { ++ _busyCount; }
    public void Dispose() { -- _busyCount; }
    public bool Busy { get { return _busyCount > 0; } }
    int _busyCount;
}
```

Взят [тут](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,390). Ничего особенного, это если не надо работать с неуправляемыми ресурсами.

ВАЖНО: при работе с неуправляемыми ресурсам надо использовать [SafeHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.110).aspx).
Пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482450/196972), а краткое описание под скриншотом.
Почитайте описание класса в MSDN, посмотрите на [реализацию в исходниках](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs,743afbddafaea263), также посмотрите базовые классы. Очевидно, что там все достаточно сложно. Поэтому не придумывайте велосипеды, несмотря на то, что некоторые это предлагают с серьезным видом :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как использования SafeHandle?

Например надо с помощью WinAPI функции [FindFirstFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364419(v=vs.85).aspx) получить информацию о папке. Функция возвращает HANDLE -- это неуправляемый ресурс, который обязательно надо освободить с помощью WinAPI функции [FindClose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364413(v=vs.85).aspx).

В такой ситуации надо определить класс SafeHandle

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
class SafeHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid {
    private SafeHandle() : base(true) { }
    protected override bool ReleaseHandle() { 
        return FindClose(this.handle); }
}
```

И указать SafeHandle в определении функции

```
static extern SafeHandle FindFirstFileEx(...)
```

В своем классе пишем

```
var h = FindFirstFileEx(...);
```

Таким образом мы получаем ссылку на специальную обертку над неуправляемым ресурсом. И даже если произойдет неожиданное прерывание потока или переполнение стека и т.д., то будет вызвана функция FindClose, т.е. гарантированно будет закрыт дескриптор неуправляемого ресурса.

Работающий пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482450/196972).

Answer (score 6):

Отвечая на ваш вопрос об обнулении ссылок -- нет, обнулять их не нужно, поскольку это не поможет. Более того, в вашем случае метод `Dispose` вам совсем не нужен. Почему, читайте ниже.

---

Существует только две ситуации, когда необходимо реализовывать `IDisposable`:

- В классе есть управляемые (`IDisposable`) ресурсы
- В классе есть неуправляемые ресурсы

**В классе есть управляемые (IDisposable) ресурсы**

У всех таких ресурсов нужно вызвать метод `Dispose()` или его аналог (например, `Close()`). Зануллять такие ресурсы в 99.9% случаев нет необходимости, поскольку они в любом случае будут собраны сборщиком мусора. (Зануллять можно, если эти ресурсы занимают большой объем памяти и вы хотите "посигнализировать" сборщику мусора чтобы он побыстрее их собрал. Но *никаких гарантий* это не дает.)

```
public sealed class SingleApplicationInstance : IDisposable
{
    private Mutex namedMutex;
    private bool namedMutexCreatedNew;

    public SingleApplicationInstance(string applicationName)
    {
        this.namedMutex = new Mutex(false, applicationName, out namedMutexCreatedNew);
    }

    public bool AlreadyExisted
    {
        get { return !this.namedMutexCreatedNew; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        namedMutex.Close();
    }
}
```

**В классе есть неуправляемые ресурсы**

Реализация `Dispose()` для таких классов должна "закрыть" ресурс (как -- зависит от самого ресурса) и вызвать `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);`. Плюс обязательно должен быть реализован финализатор, в котором должно вызываться "закрытие" ресурса. Т.о. гарантируется, что ресурс будет закрыт в любом случае -- либо программистом (при этом финализатор вызва не будет), либо сборщиком мусора (путем вызова финализатора).

```
public sealed class WindowStationHandle : IDisposable
{
    public WindowStationHandle(IntPtr handle)
    {
        this.Handle = handle;
    }

    public WindowStationHandle() : this(IntPtr.Zero)
    {
    }

    public bool IsInvalid
    {
        get { return (this.Handle == IntPtr.Zero); }
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; set; }

    private void CloseHandle()
    {
        if (this.IsInvalid)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!NativeMethods.CloseWindowStation(this.Handle))
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("CloseWindowStation: " + new Win32Exception().Message);
        }

        this.Handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.CloseHandle();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~WindowStationHandle()
    {
        this.CloseHandle();
    }
}

internal static partial class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool CloseWindowStation(IntPtr hWinSta);
}
```

---

Полная версия о правильном применении `IDisposable` -- в моем [переводе](http://habrahabr.ru/post/89720/) на Хабре.

Comment: Для второго случая я бы рекомендовал использовать `SafeHandle`. Из достоинств - `SafeHandle` срабатывает даже если выгружается домен приложения, кроме того `SafeHandle` поддерживается `P/Invoke` (исчезает окно, в котором неуправляемый ресурс уже создан - но его дескриптор еще никуда не сохранен)

Comment: Ну и наконец - получается меньше кода, поскольку все основное уже реализовано в базовом классе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, верно. В статье об этом упоминается. А это просто учебный пример.

Comment: В примере не упоминается, потому и пишу...

Comment: при работе с неуправляемыми ресурсам не надо придумывать велосипед. Есть [специальный SafeHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил `bool disposed`. Чтобы в остальных методах бросать `ObjectDisposedException`, а в `Dispose` проверять `if (disposed) return;`

Comment: Коллеги, вы немного путаете. Речь в моем ответе идет не о правильной реализации метода `Dispose`, а о том, в каких случаях использовать `IDisposable`. А посему примеры -- учебные, для понимания. В конце концов, если вам хочется подискутировать, -- напишите автору и поучите его жизни: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/08/how-to-implement-idisposable-and.html

Answer (score 1):

Паттерн `IDisposable` в вашем случае не применим, т.к. он служит для освобождения внешних ресурсов, а не памяти. Ресурс в это случае - это нечто, что требует явного закрытия - файл, сокет, транзакция. Память же в .NET ручного освобождения не требует.

Кроме освобождения ресурсов `IDisposable` часто реализуют только ради использования синтаксиса `using`, но это тоже явно не ваш случай.

---

Освобождением памяти в .NET занимается сборщик мусора. Когда он решает, что память стоило бы немного освободить, он отслеживает достижимость объектов от т.н. корней - локальных переменных, глобальных статический полей и прочих способов хоть как-то добраться до объекта из кода.

Предположим, у вас есть локальная переменная, ссылающаяся на объект вашего класса. Сборщик мусора проверяет достижимость:

```
локальная переменная → ваш объект → большая строка
```

видит, что строка используется, и не освобождает из нее память.

Но вот вы вышли из метода. Или код в методе прошел дальше последнего упоминания вашей переменной в коде. На ваш объект больше нет ссылок ниоткуда:

```
ваш объект → большая строка
```

И объект, и большая строка недостижимы. И сборщик мусора их спокойно сжигает при следующей сборке.

Изменило бы ситуацию зануление ссылок (в Dispose, или в другом методе)? Совсем нет. Зануление в этой ситуации - совершенно излишне.

Answer (score -1):

Да, можно. null.

Но вообще, есть вероятность, что это просто лишнее. Такое имеет смысл делать только если эти строки реально влияют на память, а объект, содержащий их, живёт значительно дольше. В любом случае, странно использовать именно dispose для этого.

Кстати, рекомендуется проверять, был ли вызван dispose в других методах. В твоём случае, вероятно, в методе, использующем эти строки.