# Простая реализация Финализатора и IDisposable

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

Разбираюсь сейчас с финализатором и методом Dispose в c#. В плане их нужности и выполняемых функции, какую роль играют и тд. -  в принципе все более-менее понятно. 
С тем же финализатором - когда происходит сборка мусора, объекты на которые находятся в первом поколении удаляются сразу, а те которые находятся во втором - позже. Связано это с тем, что кто-то объекту еще чем-то используется.

Например: В программе мы создали файл, открыли его, записали в него информацию. При сборке мусора мы должны удалять этот файл, но удалить мы его не можем, так как файл не закрыт, поэтому закрытие файла реализует финализатор. Я правильно все понял?

Не могли бы привести простой, рабочий пример(описывающий данную работу с файлом) с финализатором и dispose?

Comment: см. [Правильная реализация метода Dispose](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483938)

Comment: _"создали файл, открыли его, записали в него информацию.."_ -- и после этого надо вызвать .Close() или .Dispose() -- в этих методах реализовано освобождение дескриптора в Windows и файл будет закрыт.

Comment: финализатор лучше не определять в своем классе. т.к. финализатор может быть вызван до завершения работы конструктора объекта. чтобы такого не было надо наследовать CriticalFinalizerObject

Answer (score 4):

Обычно вам не нужна реализация `Dispose`, потому что классы стандартной библиотеки сами реализуют `IDisposable`, и вам нужно просто применить `using`. Пример с файлом:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path/to/file"))
{
    // работаем с файлом...
}
```

Суть работы здесь простая: объект удаляется как только он не нужен больше через `Dispose`.

Однако если вам нужно держать `IDisposable`-объект среди свойств вашего класса, ваш класс должен по идее сам имплементировать `IDisposable`.

В случае, когда у вас просто одно или несколько `IDisposable`-полей, вам подходит простой вариант реализации паттерна:

```
// только для случая, когда у нас нет потомков
sealed class ResourceHolder : IDisposable
{
    SomeResource resource;
    bool isDisposed = false;

    public ResourceHolder()
    {
        resource = AllocateResource();
    }

    public void Use()
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException();
        // ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // мы уже умерли? валим отсюда
        if (isDisposed) return; // идемпотентность Dispose

        // освободим ресурсы
        resource.Dispose();

        // и запомним, что мы уже умерли
        isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Здесь вам вовсе не нужен финализатор, т. к. вы не пользуетесь неуправляемыми ресурсами.

Суть работы здесь немного сложнее. Если объект убивается через `Dispose`, то вызывается `resource.Dispose`, при этом ресурс освобождается (например, файл закрывается). Если объект не убивается через `Dispose`, то на `resource` в какой-то момент больше не будет корневых ссылок, и для *его* неуправляемых подресурсов вызовется финализатор, и освободит их (например, закроет файл). Это, как вы видите, простой случай.

Для общего случая, когда в классе есть как управляемые, так и неуправляемые ресурсы, да ещё и возможно наследование, подойдёт полная форма паттерна. Но это **не рекомендованный** метод, т. к. код получается избыточно сложным.

```
class ResourceHolder : IDisposable
{
    SomeUnmanagedResource uResource;
    SomeManagedResource mResource;
    bool isDisposed = false;

    public ResourceHolder()
    {
        uResource = AllocateUnmanagedResource();
        mResource = AllocateManagedResource();

        // если здесь происходит дополнительная инициализация, то нужно,
        // чтобы финализатор не съел объект до конца конструктора.
        // для этого последней строчкой прописываем
        GC.KeepAlive(this);
    }

    void Use()
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException();
        // ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(isDisposing: true);
        // мы закрыли ресурс, финализатор не нужен
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        // мы уже умерли? валим отсюда
        if (isDisposed) return; // идемпотентность Dispose

        // мы вызваны из Dispose?
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            // освободим управляемые ресурсы
            mResource.Dispose();
        }

        // в любом случае освободим неуправляемые ресурсы
        // но нам может понадобиться проверка того, а был ли реально аллоцирован
        // неуправляемый ресурс (например, его выделение могло бросить исключение)
        if (uResource was indeed allocated)
            FreeUnmanagedResource(uResource);

        // и запомним, что мы уже умерли -- это должно быть последней строкой
        isDisposed = true;

        // GC.KeepAlive(this) не нужно, т. к. в предыдущей строке объект
        // всё ещё достижим (isDisposed -- поле объекта)
    }

    ~ResourceHolder()
    {
        // раз мы в финализаторе, то нас забыли за-Dispose-ить
        // надо освободить неуправляемые ресурсы
        // освобождать управляемые ресурсы здесь опасно (и вообще запрещено)
        Dispose(isDisposing: false);
    }
}
```

Видите, насколько реализация стала сложнее?

Возможно, именно поэтому гайдлайн (ссылка ниже) советует не держать в качестве полей неуправляемые ресурсы, а лишь [`SafeHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) на них (точнее, производный от него класс). При этом паттерн упрощается до того варианта, что приведён выше, плюс отпадает необходимость в финализаторе. И сложный случай сводится к простому.

Вот [Майкрософтовский гайдлайн](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) по этому поводу.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34900/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-----idisposable).

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю. Частный случай с файлом, который надо удалить после закрытия - в WIN API есть такой флаг, [`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE).

Это дает гарантию очистки файла на уровне ОС, хотя я бы не рекомендовал совать такой код во все проекты подряд.