# Что такое IDisposable простыми словами

Tags: c#

В ответе на вопрос об интерфейсе IDisposable прочел, что IDisposable используют в тех случаях, когда автоматическая сборка мусора не работает. т.е. IDisposable работает в связке с using и при выходе из using { } вызывается принудительно метод Disposable, правильно? получается что IDisposable - механизм для освобождения неуправляемых ресурсов и всегда срабатывает с директивой using { } ?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Правильная реализация метода Dispose](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483938/186999)

Comment: @Grundy, вроде был вопрос лучше того, который ты нашёл. Скорее всего у VladD.

Comment: @Grundy, я [нашёл](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A10105+%5BC%23%5D+IDisposable+is%3Aq)

Comment: Пользуйтесь поиском, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну всё же расписано в вопросе @VladD...